# Need assistance for parsing XML in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ArrayOfAlertConditionShelve xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Alerting" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <AlertConditionShelve>
                <AndThenTimeInterval i:nil="true"/>
                <ChainType>Trigger</ChainType>
                <ConditionTypeID>Core.Dynamic</ConditionTypeID>
                <Configuration>
                        <AlertConditionDynamic xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Alerting.Plugins.Conditions.Dynamic" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                <ExprTree xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Alerting">
                                        <a:Child>
                                                <a:Expr>
                                                        <a:Child>
                                                                <a:Expr>
                                                                        <a:Child/>
                                                                        <a:NodeType>Field</a:NodeType>
                                                                        <a:Value>Orion.NPM.Interfaces|TypeDescription</a:Value>
                                                                </a:Expr>
                                                                <a:Expr>
                                                                        <a:Child i:nil="true"/>
                                                                        <a:NodeType>Constant</a:NodeType>
                                                                        <a:Value>IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregate</a:Value>
                                                                </a:Expr>
                                                        </a:Child>
                                                        <a:NodeType>Operator</a:NodeType>
                                                        <a:Value>=</a:Value>
                                                </a:Expr>
........
```

This is my xml string.

I have the following code

```
def ParsingXMLviaDOM(xmlstr):
    xmlparse = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlstr)
    xmlstr = xmlparse.toprettyxml()
  
    conditions = xmlparse.getElementsByTagName("a:Expr")  
    print ' '
    for condition in conditions:
        con = condition.getElementsByTagName("a:Value")
        print con[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

The output is as follows:

```
Orion.NPM.Interfaces|TypeDescription
Orion.NPM.Interfaces|TypeDescription
IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregate
Orion.NPM.Interfaces|InPercentUtil
Orion.NPM.Interfaces|InPercentUtil
85
Orion.Nodes|SysName|Node
Orion.Nodes|SysName|Node
tdc-agg-ha-a1-10508
```

Value tag exists in different level. How do I extract them? Right now I have a duplicated lines and no value for one level higher.

I need to get '=' value.

Anyone can help on this.  thanks a lot !!

Comment: Upload a **VALID** XML document and explain what is the expected output. Explain why the code does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xml.etree.ElementTree` and the `findall()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("tom.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Alerting"

for elem in root.findall(".//{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Alerting}Value"):
    print(elem.text)
```

Output:

```
Orion.NPM.Interfaces|TypeDescription
IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregate
=
```

And if you are only interessted in "=" :

```
for k, v in enumerate(root.findall(".//{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Alerting}Value")):
    if k == 2:
        print(v.text)
```

Output:

```
=
```

Same as, if you use short form  `findall(".//{*}Value")`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("tom.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for k, v in enumerate(root.findall(".//{*}Value")):
    if k == 2:
        print(v.text)
```